# Batch script to taskkill search by "Command Line" arguments

Tags: powershell

I need a batch script to taskkill by **"Command Line"** arguments ("Command Line" from Windows Task Manager). To clarify - these processes are **dotnet core** applications. They are started via:

**dotnet** MyDotnetCoreApp.dll xxx yyy

If you examine under Task Managers,

1. Name = dotnet.exe
2. Image path name = C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
3. Command line = dotnet MyDotnetCoreApp.dll xxx yyy

I need a batch script to kill these tasks, probably with **taskkill**

**OPTION 1** is Taskkill by PID but how my script search "Command Line" arguments for MyDotnetCoreApp?

**OPTION 2** is taskkill by Image Name? This is no go as my server has many dotnet core applications, if kill my Image Name, all dotnet core processes be killed

I been researching:

https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program

https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-contains

I can't get this to work, not good at **PowerShell**:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | Select-Object Handle
```

Here'd get a list of PIDs with which to kill.

Two challenges:

**First Challenge**, my WHERE clause dont work:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | where {$_.CommandLine -like '*MyDotnetCoreApp*'} | Select-Object Handle
```

I checked further, found out these "CommandLine" was NOT populated for these WmiObjects (omg!):
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | Select-Object ProcessId, Name, CSName, Caption, CommandLine, ExecutablePath

I later then found out "CommandLine" would have been populated IF you **run Powershell as Administrator**!?! (Powershell so cryptic!)

In the end - First challenged was **resolved**:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | where {$_.CommandLine -like '*MyDotnetApp*'} | Select-Object ProcessId, Name, CSName, Caption, CommandLine, ExecutablePath
```

**Second Challenge**: How to kill it? **Found it!!**

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | where {$_.CommandLine -like '*MyDotnetCoreApp*'}).Terminate()
```

So this is actually resolved!

Answer (score 2):

Run Powershell as Administrator! Download **psexec** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

```
psexec -u Administrator -p SomeSecret powershell
```

Then from **Powershell**:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dotnet.exe'" | where {$_.CommandLine -like '*MyDotnetCoreApp*'}).Terminate()
```

Now as separate question, can you do this one line? Below wont work because -Filter has quotes in it!

```
psexec -u Administrator -p SomeSecret powershell -Command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ""name = 'dotnet.exe'"" | where {$_.CommandLine -like '*MyDotnetCoreApp*'}).Terminate() "
```

As hacky work around, I removed **-Filter** clause (How unfortunate, not sure how to escape quotes):

```
psexec -u Administrator -p SomeSecret powershell -Command "(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | where {$_.CommandLine -like '*MyDotnetCoreApp*'}).Terminate() "
```

Comment: Use `\"` to escape embedded double quotes when calling the PowerShell CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as a regular user, unless the process is running as administrator?.  Unfortunately, the filter syntax is like sql here, where '%' is the wildcard.  Piping to where-object would probably work just as well.

```
get-wmiobject win32_process -filter "commandline like '%dotnet.exe%MyDotnetCoreApp%'" | 
  remove-wmiobject

get-wmiobject win32_process | where commandline -like '*dotnet.exe*MyDotnetCoreApp*' | 
  remove-wmiobject
```

Comment: I realized for "CommandLine" to be populated (i.e. not null), you'd need start Powershell "Run as Administrator" ("Run as Different user" under Administrators Group won't do it)

Comment: Works ok for me as a regular user in windows 10.